# Are Physical Education classes mandatory by law?

Tags: law, education, us-state-laws

I'm extremely irritated for many reasons that physical education classes are still mandatory in my high school. I am prepared to write a letter to the principal or superintendent with a long list of reasons that P.E classes should be optional. I also have several ideas of ways to fill the schedule gap for those who opt out. My question is, even if i can persuade someone on a local level to change this inefficiency, are they mandated to keep Physical Education classes mandatory by law?

If that is the case I am willing to send my ideas to lawmakers. Also, would it be a state or a federal law?

Comment: it depends on the state

Comment: I do not think it is law but... The DoE has certain criteria to be awarded funds.  One of those criteria is that there are PE Classes and that there is a certain percentage of compliance with the required participation rate.  The amount of money that the School district is penalized by is pretty signifigant for non compliance... If I can find some good online references ill post this as an answer.  Unless someone beats me too it.

Comment: What state are you in?

Comment: Not a political answer: But if your goal is to get out of PE, many schools have exceptions that you can apply for--such as if you already partake in extra curricular physical activities.

Comment: I realise this is very old, but this is not an on-topic question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on a state, since educational legislation is mostly a state province.

---

Predictably, California has an <strike>app</strike> law for that:

> *What are the required instructional minutes for an elementary school maintaining any of grades one through eight?*
>
> If a school is identified as an elementary school in the County-District-School (CDS) code system, EC Section 23 states that, “Notwithstanding the provisions of Sections 51210 and 51222, **instruction in physical education in an elementary school maintaining any of grades one to eight shall be for a total period of time of not less than 200 minutes each ten schooldays**, exclusive of recesses and the lunch period." (src: http://www.cde.ca.gov/pd/ca/pe/physeducfaqs.asp)

CA Educational Code (http://law.onecle.com/california/education/index.html) lists several sections clearly dealing with PhysEd, most in 512xx range:

- California Education Code Section 51210.1 (a) (1) The Legislature finds and declares all of the following: (A) The Education Code currently mandates 200 minutes of physical education every 10 schooldays...
- California Education Code Section 51210.2 (a) The Legislature hereby finds and declares that the physical fitness and motor development of children in the public elementary schools is of equal importance...
- California Education Code Section 51210.3 (a) The governing board of a school district may designate a credentialed teacher at each elementary school as a science coach, or provide staff development...

---

Same thing in New Jersey:

> *Are all students required to participate in the health and physical education program?*
>
> [N.J.S.A. 18A:35-7](http://www.nj.gov/njded/code/current/title6a/chap8.pdf) requires every pupil, except kindergarten pupils, attending public schools to take such courses. However, the core standards establish requirements for students in grades K-12. (src: http://www.state.nj.us/education/genfo/faq/faq_chpe.htm)

---

For other states, googling for "physical education mandatory law " yields good results based on the above 2 states.

Comment: Thanks for telling me where to look. Turns out my state has made it mandatory too. Hopefully someday that will change.